# Sorting by absolute value without changing to absolute value

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I want to sort a tuple using abs() without actually changing the elements of the tuple to positive values.

```
def sorting(numbers_array):
    return sorted(numbers_array, key = abs(numbers_array))


sorting((-20, -5, 10, 15))
```

According to the python wiki (https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions), the sorted(list, key=) function is suppose to sort with the parameter *key* without actually altering the elements of the list. However, abs() only takes int() and I haven't worked out a way to make that tuple into an int, if that's what I need to do.

Comment: Wait, you are trying to sort a tuple, not a list here. Is that intentional?

Comment: `sorted((-20, -5, 10, 15), key=lambda v: -v if v<0 else v)` is an alternate to the more correct `sorted((-20, -5, 10, 15), key=abs)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to give `key` a **callable**, a function or similar to call; it'll be called for each element in the sequence being sorted. `abs` can be that callable:

```
sorted(numbers_array, key=abs)
```

You instead passed in the *result* of the `abs()` call, which indeed doesn't work with a whole list.

Demo:

```
>>> def sorting(numbers_array):
...     return sorted(numbers_array, key=abs)
... 
>>> sorting((-20, -5, 10, 15))
[-5, 10, 15, -20]
```

Comment: I didn't copy paste your answer. I was just typing it when you answered ;)

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome: I didn't think you did :-) For one, I used PEP-8 spacing for the keyword argument, which you didn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just googled PEP-8, there is a lot of code guidelines.

Comment: I just tried this on a different website and it doesn't work, whereas it worked on pythontutor. The error I get is sorting() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

Comment: @NickKremer: ah, `sorting()` is not the same function as `sorted()`. Your error message tells you you are calling the wrong function there..

Comment: I see. I had an error in my code, its working now. I was trying to call the function 'sorting()' instead of 'sorted()'

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to sort these 4 values (-20, -5, 10, 15) the desired output would be:
[-5, 10, 15, -20], because you are taking the absolute value.

So here is the solution:

```
def sorting(numbers_array):
    return sorted(numbers_array, key = abs)


print(sorting((-20, -5, 10, 15)))
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Edited. I'm still using Python 2.7, because not all is supperted yet by 3.x But I am sure you know more about that than me

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [-1, 1, -2, 20, -30, 10]
>>>print(sorted(lst, key=abs))
>>>[-1, 1, -2, 10, 20, -30]
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation as to how your answer solves the problem?  This helps future users who search for the same problem.