# Sort a list of integers on absolute values with higher precedence positive number

Tags: python, sorting

How do I sort a list of integers based on their absolute values such that the positive number gets a higher precedence -

**Sample Input**

```
lst = [1, -3, 3, -3, 12, 10]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[1, 3, -3, -3, 10, 12]
```

I am able to do it right now with a code like this, but I am bothered by that arbitrary `0.1` in the function and wonder if there is a cleaner way

**My code**

```py
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x) if x >= 0 else abs(x) + 0.1)
# [1, 3, -3, -3, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting by absolute value without changing to absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905351/sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-to-absolute-value)

Comment: can we mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: No, not really - if I can summarize - that question is asking how to provide a `key` while I am asking effectively what `key` should I provide for this particular case

Comment: same problem, different wording, same solution. it is duplicate. you are asking for what key to give and there is asking how to give a key. in my opinion question should be marked as  duplicate

Comment: No, it is not - the problem I have is how do I sort such that positive numbers get a higher precedence than negative numbers when there is a tie. The other one is asking how to sort on absolute values. The current version of the code that I give with the question already uses the `abs` function - the point is how do I give a different rank to, say, `abs(-3)` and `abs(3)`. Which is what all the answers are about too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution is having a tuple as a sorting key:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x < 0))
```

To understand it better:

```
 1 ~ (1, False)  ~ (1, 0)
-3 ~ (3, True)   ~ (3, 1)
 3 ~ (3, False)  ~ (3, 0)
-3 ~ (3, True)   ~ (3, 1)
12 ~ (12, False) ~ (12, 0)
10 ~ (10, False) ~ (10, 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom comparator function which returns a tuple of size 2. The first value of the tuple is for absolute value and the second value is for ordering negative and positive values with the same absolute value.

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), -x))
# [1, 3, -3, -3, 10, 12]
```

---

For each value in the list values compared would be:

```
1  -> (1, -1)
3  -> (3, -3)
-3 -> (3,  3)
10 -> (10, -10)
12 -> (12, -12)
```

This way positive values are pushed to the beginning and negatives values to the end in each group.

Answer (score 4):

As often the case, two simple sorts are probably more efficient here than one sort using tuples:

```
lst.sort(reverse=True)
lst.sort(key=abs)
```

This takes advantage of the sort function being stable, so the order from the first sort is preserved to break ties in the second sort. Also see Python's [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) about this technique.

Btw yours would be a bit shorter and faster without the unnecessary `abs` (you already know the sign):

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0.5 - x)
```

Also, the sort function is optimized for cases where all values have the same type, so if we simply add 0.0 to non-negative `x` to make it a `float` as well, this optimization gets used. Btw adding a single `.` to Jupri's currently deleted answer fixes it and then it's quite neat and similarly fast.

Benchmark for something like your "few 100 elements long" lists and also longer lists:

```
500 random integers from -500 to 500
 82.9 μs ± 0.2 μs  Kelly
113.6 μs ± 0.5 μs  original_mod2
117.5 μs ± 0.4 μs  Jupri
191.7 μs ± 0.3 μs  Yevhen
196.2 μs ± 0.6 μs  Ch3ster
215.0 μs ± 0.7 μs  original_mod1
233.5 μs ± 0.5 μs  original

100,000 random integers from -100,000 to 100,000
 39.4 ms ± 0.1 ms  Kelly
 40.2 ms ± 0.4 ms  original_mod2
 41.6 ms ± 0.3 ms  Jupri
 90.2 ms ± 0.5 ms  original_mod1
 94.9 ms ± 0.4 ms  original
115.9 ms ± 2.7 ms  Yevhen
131.5 ms ± 2.6 ms  Ch3ster
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTBjptADL3nK3wDNoSSjbKqotJLb@21lyqKEBtMghYGNDOssor2o3rvqR/QX0rtmaHApqqU5pAEj/3mvWeb9kUfG7F638rLJccCGlkeSpFVfqV0sJkBfSTqTgpQjdSYczyEJ3xJqqx@zDM4bSB7VP4pgLKAE3xMIAasFPbROcTRMpjNxuBp3eTLW244vQWPo/Xi9BfU@5tQ53EU/wv5C1bVywiR/kEyAZT4jFJh8lV2GPQ5EWf4fBd5EIy50KFF/obPRxS3kPWtnyGR/QBx4Bh@Oq6URvlfQCTToXzuWlne3PEF9ZUAik7sFdmy7fsQTvs8fbwPrauhsyDsJYSWxW42K@uWLgaZibypZ4VsatBljaUGd0KUs67SKUclZMocS5updKZLpUui5LJrzOgWpXN8tmo1Ku0L7l2LmVYhdKLslRMDof3CO4tN@OooAIXwQG0Gc8N5Yc50AybJIwu4kjmwDWf2YwPbHRSNBH6gevOrXk0iU2CWyuegu9cgqGG4DNqWE3bBdrPa/UmqBSWxJF@70eKPyrmUJU7Cro8kpxZ3S1xt1tGyeIVawc/vcFa5ia36mMerwF5AkoBXK88uRF/94Kp//RiVP7hyDnrWCJadsmZy74D@cj2SaBfI2hrtj025R@XbvAV1RMyXNJdPiRgk4KnFPRdNXkyDQguljl1RVGgcHem/6sDAxBhOsPEk8oa7m5BgWmZKY6o1Y@cHV4cSFY0nJfCdU77D1fMEfAcAC8IL4F0/kVfZmVLIG@FwE@fKVV6OlUua6hyGKcraFgXNVzA0q3fIjZ4xyi68GdORersdo@ENTXGUpiKrMU2D0Q7RBWbR1nEcgvnyaEhoW0x0Gd/drUOglwMPWnC5/AY)):

```
def original(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x) if x >= 0 else abs(x) + 0.1)

def original_mod1(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0.5-x)

def original_mod2(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x+0.0 if x >= 0 else 0.5-x)

def Kelly(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
    lst.sort(key=abs)
    return lst

def Yevhen(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x < 0))

def Ch3ster(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), -x))

def Jupri(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x-.1))

funcs = [original, original_mod1, original_mod2, Kelly, Yevhen, Ch3ster, Jupri]

import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from statistics import mean, stdev

def test(n, repeats, unit):
    print(f'{n:,} random integers from {-n:,} to {n:,}')

    times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
    def stats(func):
        ts = sorted(times[func])[:3]
        mn = mean(ts)
        sd = stdev(ts)
        return f'{mn*1e3:5.1f} ms ± {sd*1e3:3.1f} ms ' if unit == 'ms' else f'{mn*1e6:5.1f} μs ± {sd*1e6:3.1f} μs '

    for _ in range(15):
        lst = random.choices(range(-n, n+1), k=n)
        expect = original(lst)
        random.shuffle(funcs)
        for func in funcs:
            t = 0
            for _ in range(repeats):
                t0 = timer()
                result = func(lst)
                t += (timer() - t0) / repeats
                assert result == expect
                del result
            times[func].append(t)

    for func in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(func), func.__name__)
    print()

test(500, 500, 'μs')
test(10**5, 1, 'ms')
```

Comment: Very clever one.

Comment: @Ch3steR Not really. Standard method. I wonder why someone voted it "not useful".

Comment: You are actually right! Tested your solution and mine. Yours was more than twice faster. Nice solution

Comment: I see that this way is faster than @YevhenKuzmovych method, my lists are few 100 elements long - but I interpret the other method as "first sort by absolute value, then by whether they are positive" - this is a little bit harder to interpret for me, but that could just be me...

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Well, it's by far not the first time I've done and benchmarked multiple vs single sort, that's why I was quite confident :-). Added two benchmarks now myself (took a while since I'm currently only working on a phone).

Comment: @Mortz Added a second benchmark with such shorter lists. Yeah, I guess the single sorts might be a little easier to understand, at least if you're familiar with those but aren't with using multiple sorts.

Comment: @Mortz Btw yours gets a little shorter and faster when you remove the abs: `lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0.5 - x`

Comment: Nice!. Btw, I learned about a lot from your [tio](https://tio.run/##nZJNb4MwDIbv@RW@TEs2ilKhSVM1dtlx1112QimYEhUCckJFfz1LmtKP3bacgu338WuH4eia3mSvA82z7oaeHJAyVd@xmvoOnO5QOzhnKqzV2LoiRAmUPaWJMR@HnvROG9Xy1jqxYeAPoRvJgPVSrEI8gT0e81Z120rBtAG1tXwSoGuY4D0HCdhaXKLPINO1iPBPbNvjDdnfIL8DEx6QLOZfNKJYatJQwUNPzxS3nnwykr/x0KD5i2ke/SXe8xtIcXb40WTWIf0LtJoCxfiJXqRkcbb4CGnZ9LpEy/3nDvnKJGC8YJ8bwXAasAyld5tnrO4JCtAGoiY72wnhejRlyCyKJC42OW8hWaaIinCc9A1Or8zFJfirw1pKKa6SOLv1/4mXho7R14V4BcLK8y@JgbRxfFHmEOdL4BEesgpGGy7AHTzBGjO/hIBOi8KoDosi8iNCzPMP) code, including about the platform itself. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mortz Oh, I just realized I can make yours almost as fast as mine. Will post that later if nobody else does first.

Comment: @Mortz Updated the answer with more solutions, better benchmarks, and more explanation.

Comment: @Ch3steR I mean, that technique is even described int the HOW TO (linked to that now). Though maybe now with the added optimized original and the fixed Jupri's, there's something clever here :-)

Comment: Thank you. Jupri's solution (or the one you posted) is beautiful, and very intuitive in retrospect. Sort being optimized for same type also makes sense but is there anywhere I can read about that?

Comment: @Mortz It's mentioned at the bottom of [listsort.txt](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt) and you can find it in [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) by searching for `unsafe`.