# Sorting integers by absolute value, weighting positive and negative

Tags: python, list, sorting, return-value, absolute

I am trying to create a code list that follows this parameter.  This takes in an unsorted list and returns a sorted list according to the absolute sorting where the positive value will be considered smaller. The original list which is passed in should be unchanged. below is what i have so far how do i switch the numbers in the list.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))

list_1 = list(map(int, input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]
print("\nList is - ", list_1)
def absolute_value(num):
    return abs(num)


list_2 = list_1.sort(key = absolute_value)
print(list_2)
def length_of_list(list_2):
    for i in list_2:
        for j in list_2:
            if abs(i) == abs(j) and i < j:
```

Comment: Try also to clean-up the code and focus on just the sorting function, which takes a list and returns another list with sorted values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905464/7451892 sorting based on absolute value though the abs has the negative values smaller than the positive

Comment: Another suggestion is to give variables some meaningful names: maybe "unsorted_list" instead of "list_1" or "sort_me" instead of "length_of_list" (?); this will make the flow more clear and help you find the solution

Comment: I don't understand what your actual problem is, but `list.sort` sorts the list in place and returns `None`. If you want a sorted copy, use the builtin [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

Answer (score 1):

This almost does what you need:

```
xs = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
xs.sort(key=abs)
print(xs)
```

But the positive numbers can end up after the negative ones:

```
[0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3]
```

If you want the negative values to always end up after the positive ones, this is one way to do it:

```
def sort_val(x):
    return abs(x)*2 + int(x < 0)  # e.g. -3 becomes 7, 3 becomes 6

xs = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
xs.sort(key=sort_val)
print(xs)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *know* the index of the list that you want to change, to do this you can use the `enumerate` functions

```
...
if abs(i) == abs(j) and i < j:
    list_2[idx1], list_2[idx2] = list_2[idx2], list_2[idx1]
```